# Can "older" games such as "Age of Empires", "Age of Mythology", and "Star Wars: Empire at War" be installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, games

Is it possible to put older games on Ubuntu?  I am wondering about games such as:

- Age of Empires games
- Age of Mythology games
- Star Wars: Empire at War games
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

All the games you told above is basically games that were developed to run in Windows. But you can run it on your Ubuntu system with varying degrees of success using:

## [wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine) [image: Install wine]

or

## [playonlinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/playonlinux) [image: Install playonlinux]

(A GUI for Wine allowing to install Windows games and applications on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to play windows based games in ubuntu you could try 'wine'
[http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu.)

also for older games like 'DAVE' you could try DOSBox

you can get both of them in software center